# How to show a error message if the data is already inserted in the database in c#

Tags: c#

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KING;Initial Catalog=semasinter;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into StudentApplication", conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "spinsertstudentapplication";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_id", TextBox1.Text); 
    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Select_Course", ddlCourse.SelectedValue);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select_Country", TextBox4.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select_State", TextBox2.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select_Franchise", TextBox3.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Select_Sensei", ddlSensei.SelectedValue);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", TextBox6.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enter_Student_Name", TextBox7.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enter_Student_Address", TextBox8.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Students_Father_Name", TextBox9.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_DOB", TextBox10.Text);
    if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = true;

    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = false;

    }
    command.Parameters.Add("@Enter_Kyu", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox11.Text;       
    conn.Open();
    int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();   //// in these line i got a error message   
    conn.Close();

}
```

can u help me friends plz

Comment: Help? With what? You did not ask a question.

Comment: what errormessage do you get ?

Comment: Tell us a bit more about the table you are inserting into. Does it have any UNIQUE indexes? Are you getting any exceptions now, if so what do they say?

Comment: different question title, and different question in post?? I answered your question depends on title

Comment: Do **not** keep repeating the question. If you want to add detail, *edit this one*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCheckDupEmployee]
@empId int,
@empName varchar(100),
@empCode varchar(10),
@Message varchar(1000) OUTPUT

AS
SELECT @Message =''

BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE empName = @empName  AND empId NOT IN(@empId)--AND cmpDeleteFlag = 0
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT @Message ='Same Employee Name Exists!'
    RETURN
    END
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE empCode = @empCode  AND empId NOT IN(@empId)--AND cmpDeleteFlag = 0
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT @Message ='Same Employee Code Exists!'
    RETURN
    END
RETURN
END
```

this checks duplication and sends back a message.
Now give this message string to a messagebox.show() method..

ex;

```
messagebox.show(msg,APPName);
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the problem - you don't know how to display an error message?  It may be worth mentioning that populating a primary key with user-inputted data is generally bad practise.

To be honest it looks like the solution you're asking for is to put `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` in your catch block, but that doesn't deal with the deeper issues behind this code.  Also this assumes that you're in a WinForms or WPF application, which may not be the case.  You should possibly post more context and a more specific question...

Answer (score 0):

You can check DB with current studentId. if count return > 0 , it means there is an already data inserted for that student. The point is here where you can throw new Exception "This student is already exist"

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCheckDupEmployee]
@empId int,
@empName varchar(100),
@empCode varchar(10),
@Message varchar(1000) OUTPUT

AS
SELECT @Message =''

BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE empName = @empName  AND empId NOT IN(@empId)--AND cmpDeleteFlag = 0
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT @Message ='Same Employee Name Exists!'
    RETURN
    END
```

try this kind of query to check duplication..!!

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!